# Argument must be a dense tensor: got shape [2] but wanted [2, 563]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I was trying to train a language model with Keras on a corpus of 35 tweets.

I get the error mentioned in the title, with the following trace back:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most   recent call last)
 <ipython-input-101-5ed366712809> in <module>()
 ----> 1 create_model(X, Y, max_len, total_words)

<ipython-input-100-798dd17a8b2b> in create_model(predictors, label, max_sequence_len, total_words)
  3 
  4     model = Sequential()
 ----> 5     model.add(Embedding(total_words, 10))
  6     model.add(LSTM(150))
  7     model.add(Dropout(0.1))

  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/models.py in add(self, layer)
495                 # and create the node connecting the current layer
496                 # to the input layer we just created.
--> 497                 layer(x)
498 
499             if len(layer._inbound_nodes[-1].output_tensors) != 1:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
590                                          '`layer.build(batch_input_shape)`')
591                 if len(input_shapes) == 1:
--> 592                     self.build(input_shapes[0])
593                 else:
594                     self.build(input_shapes)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/layers/embeddings.py in build(self, input_shape)
103             regularizer=self.embeddings_regularizer,
104             constraint=self.embeddings_constraint,
--> 105             dtype=self.dtype)
106         self.built = True
107 
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
 89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name +
 90                               '` call to the Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
 ---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
 92         wrapper._original_function = func
 93         return wrapper

 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py in add_weight(self, name, shape, dtype, initializer, regularizer, trainable, constraint)
411         if dtype is None:
412             dtype = K.floatx()
--> 413         weight = K.variable(initializer(shape),
414                             dtype=dtype,
415                             name=name,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/initializers.py in __call__(self, shape, dtype)
110     def __call__(self, shape, dtype=None):
111         return K.random_uniform(shape, self.minval, self.maxval,
—-> 112                                 dtype=dtype, seed=self.seed)
113 
114     def get_config(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in random_uniform(shape, minval, maxval, dtype, seed)
 3836         seed = np.random.randint(10e6)
 3837     return tf.random_uniform(shape, minval=minval, maxval=maxval,
 -> 3838                              dtype=dtype, seed=seed)
    3839 
    3840 

   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/random_ops.py in random_uniform(shape, minval, maxval, dtype, seed, name)
232     maxval = 1
233   with ops.name_scope(name, "random_uniform", [shape, minval, maxval]) as name:
--> 234     shape = _ShapeTensor(shape)
235     minval = ops.convert_to_tensor(minval, dtype=dtype, name="min")
236     maxval = ops.convert_to_tensor(maxval, dtype=dtype, name="max")

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/random_ops.py in _ShapeTensor(shape)
 41   else:
 42     dtype = None
 ---> 43   return ops.convert_to_tensor(shape, dtype=dtype, name="shape")
 44 
 45 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, preferred_dtype)
 1009       name=name,
 1010       preferred_dtype= preferred_dtype,
 -> 1011       as_ref=False)
 1012 
 1013 

 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in internal_convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, ctx)
 1105 
 1106     if ret is None:
-> 1107       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
 1108 
 1109     if ret is NotImplemented:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in _constant_tensor_conversion_function(v, dtype, name, as_ref)
215                                          as_ref=False):
216   _ = as_ref
--> 217   return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
218 
219 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in constant(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape)
194   tensor_value.tensor.CopyFrom(
195       tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(
—> 196           value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
197   dtype_value = attr_value_pb2.AttrValue(type=tensor_value.tensor.dtype)
198   const_tensor = g.create_op(

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py in make_tensor_proto(values, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
443                          """ - got shape %s, but wanted %s.""" %
444                          (values, list(nparray.shape),
--> 445                           _GetDenseDimensions(values)))
446 
447     # python/numpy default float type is float64. We prefer float32 instead.
```

Here is all my code:

```
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.layers import Embedding, LSTM, Dense, Dropout
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.models import Sequential
import keras.utils as ku
import numpy as np

def dataset_prep(data):
    corpus = data
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(corpus)
    total_words = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1

    input_sequences = []
    for line in corpus:
        token_list = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([line])[0]
        for i in range(1, len(token_list)):
            n_gram_sequence = token_list[:i+1]
            input_sequences.append(n_gram_sequence)

    max_sequence_len = max([len(x) for x in input_sequences])
    input_sequences = np.array(pad_sequences(input_sequences, maxlen=max_sequence_len,
                                        padding='pre'))

    predictors, next_word = input_sequences[:,:-1], input_sequences[:,-1]
    label = ku.to_categorical(next_word, num_classes=total_words)
    return input_sequences[:25], input_sequences[25:], max_sequence_len, list(input_sequences)


def create_model(predictors, label, max_sequence_len, total_words):
    input_len = max_sequence_len

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(total_words, 10))
    model.add(LSTM(150))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(Dense(total_words, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
    history = model.fit(predictors, label, epochs=100, verbose=1)

    print(history.history['loss'], history.history['val_loss'])

X, Y, max_len, total_words = dataset_prep(tweet_text)
create_model(X, Y, max_len, total_words)
```

I’m using Google Colaboratory, with Keras v2.1.6 and TensorFlow 1.9.0

The code is all Python 3 with a Tesla K80 GPU for runtime compilation.

Comment: Could you please post the output of `model.summary()` and `X.shape` and `Y.shape` as well?

Comment: X.shape = [25, 26]

Comment: Y.shape = [456, 26]. Sorry I can’t post the output of model.summary() because my model object is inside the create_model function which isn’t running due to this bug.

Comment: @today Is that all right?

Comment: First, you have not specified the `input_length` argument of Embedding layer. Second, shapes of `X` and `Y` are not compatible. The first axis should be the same but it is not (i.e. 25 != 456). Note that each sample from `X` get mapped to a label from `Y`. What is the task you are working on?

Comment: @today Alright... I am working on building a language model for tweets. That said, how can I fix the first and second problems? I’m new to Keras, I used to work with PyTorch and fast.ai earlier.

Comment: What kind of language model are you trying to build? Something like word2vec?

Comment: @today Yep. Just on a smaller scale.